# Mockito.when giving InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here

Tags: java, mockito

Following is the Test Class

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AuditServiceClientTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Mock
AuditServiceClient auditServiceClient;

@Mock
ICommonDataService iCommonDataService;

private AuditServiceResponse auditServiceResponse;

private AuditServiceLog auditServiceLog;

private HttpEntity<AuditServiceLog> request;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    headers.add("X-AGS-Client-Name", "test");
    headers.add("X-AGS-Group-Name", "test");
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    auditServiceClient = new AuditServiceClientImpl();
    iCommonDataService = new CommonDataService();
    auditServiceLog = new AuditServiceLog();
    request = new HttpEntity<AuditServiceLog>(auditServiceLog, headers);
    auditServiceResponse = new AuditServiceResponse();
    auditServiceResponse.setStatus(String.valueOf(200));
    auditServiceResponse.setTimestamp("1990-01-01 00:00:01");
    auditServiceResponse.setDescription("Description");
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.anyString(), any(HttpEntity.class), ArgumentMatchers.eq(AuditServiceResponse.class)))
            .thenReturn(auditServiceResponse);
    String a = "test";
    ArrayList<Integer> mockedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Mockito.when(iCommonDataService.getEnvValue(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString()))
            .thenReturn(a);
}

@Test
public void postTest() {

    AuditServiceResponse response = null;
    try {

        response = auditServiceClient.post("endpoint", auditServiceLog, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(Integer.parseInt(response.getStatus() )== 200);
}
}
```

I am getting

> InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here

in the setUp() method on the following line:

```java
 Mockito.when(iCommonDataService.getEnvValue(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString()))
        .thenReturn(a);
```

Following is the error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:
>
> -> at com.auditService.test.AuditServiceClientTest.setUp(AuditServiceClientTest.java:72)
>
> You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
>   Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
>
> when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
>   doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
>   verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
>
> This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last
>   matcher is returning an object  like any() but the stubbed method
>   signature expect a primitive argument, in this case, use primitive
>   alternatives.
>
> when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
>   when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use
>
> Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with
>   methods that cannot be mocked. Following methods *cannot* be
>   stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode(). Mocking methods
>   declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

There are a lot of articles on this error around but none of them worked for me. Is there any issue with `Mockito.anyInt()` because `Mockito.anyString()` is being used in the previous line and that works fine. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look carefully at your test code:

```java
iCommonDataService = new CommonDataService();
    ...
Mockito.when(iCommonDataService.getEnvValue(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString()))
            .thenReturn(a);
```

You're mocking a method of an object wich is not a mock, that's the cause of the exception.

Since you already have a mock of this class declared wih `@Mock` annotation, you can simply remove this line `iCommonDataService = new CommonDataService();`. Another way could be providing a mock manually using `Mockito.mock(CommonDataService.class)`.

But, if you want to mock a method of the original object, you should use `Mockito.spy()` instead.

Comment: Just before `iCommonDataService = new CommonDataService();` I have `auditServiceClient = new AuditServiceClientImpl();` and auditServiceClient is also declared with @Mock annotation and that is working fine. Also if I remove `iCommonDataService = new CommonDataService();` this then I am getting null pointer exception.

Comment: I agree with @Pavel. Remove the constructor calls. Instead call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` at the beginning of the `setUp` method, that will inject mocks into the `@Mock`-annotated fields.

Comment: @IshanTiwary, from the code you have posted you never mock any method of `auditServiceClient`. The field `auditServiceClient` is just assigned to a new value. Concerning `NullPointerException` - try doing what @kidney suggested.

Comment: @IshanTiwary, btw, if you get an exception only at mocking `iCommonDataService.getEnvValue` then mocking of `restTemplate.postForObject` (which is also declared with `@Mock`) goes pretty well. At this point I guess that your mock injection works fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`instead of `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` which helps to resolve this issue.